# how to access multiple keys in jsonpath in one go

Tags: ruby, jsonpath

I am storing a path of a hash in config (using ruby in `JsonPath`), and in one case, I need to get multiple fields for one variable.

Example:

```
{
 "a" => 1,
 "b" => 2,
 "c" => 3,
 "d" => 4,
 "e" => 5,
}
```

For one variable, I need the value to be `3-4-5`. Is there a way to access `"c"`, `"d"`, and `"e"` from `JsonPath` in one go?

$$$$$$$$$$$$$Edit$$$$$$$$$$$$$

It seems this is currently limitation of jsonpath gem, please feel free to suggest at other gem/way to do so.

Comment: Is this a question about hash in general, or is there something specific about xpath, json, or jsonpath?

Comment: No, this is not related to Hash, it is related to jsonpath, I want to know how to access via JSON-Path, which I can store in config.

Comment: you should probably remove hash tag from the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I workaround this function by writing a small function, which takes argument as array of multiple paths of comma separated paths and returns values for those paths, following is the code:-

```
def find_multiple_path hash, path
  return path.inject([]){|tmp,p| tmp<< JsonPath.on(hash, p)}.flatten.join("-") if path and path.kind_of?(Array)

  return path.split(",").inject([]){|tmp,p| tmp<< JsonPath.on(hash, p)}.flatten.join("-") if path and path.include?(",") and path.include?("$")
end
```

Where path can be either ["$.c","$.d","$.e"] or "$.c,$.d,$.e".

Answer (score 2):

Yes..do as below using [`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
hsh = {
 "a" => 1,
 "b" => 2,
 "c" => 3,
 "d" => 4,
 "e" => 5,
}

hsh.values_at("c","d","e").join('-')
# => "3-4-5"
```

Comment: Thanks Arup, But I want to do it via JSONPath as this is config and can change, so I dont want to change the code and read the path from config.

Also I can store in multiple json-paths, but if it is possible by one path, as config can change from getting values from 3 field to 4 hash fields.